# How to implement google+ listview animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to Implement a animation experience like google+ listview.When user slide the listview,each item that first loaded in the listview will start a animation.I attempt to add animation in getview method to animate each item,but I want to confirm whether this way is a good method and do I need to extend listview class to finish this?So please give me some advice or some examples that like google+ listview.Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need to extend ListView class.

Here is an Android library that implemented Google plus-like ListView animation.

[GenericBaseAdapter.java](https://github.com/cuub/sugared-list-animations/blob/master/src/com/cuubonandroid/sugaredlistanimations/GenericBaseAdapter.java)

[GPlusListAdapter.java](https://github.com/cuub/sugared-list-animations/blob/master/src/com/cuubonandroid/sugaredlistanimations/GPlusListAdapter.java)

[MainActivity.java](https://github.com/cuub/sugared-list-animations-sample/blob/master/src/com/cuubonandroid/sugaredlistanimations/sample/MainActivity.java)

The way it works is, in the adapter's `getView` method, it animates the view if it is newly loaded.
(So, it extended Adapter, not ListView, to make an animation.)

You can also download the sample app's apk in the link in [sugared-list-animations-sample](https://github.com/cuub/sugared-list-animations-sample)

Answer (score 2):

Google Plus style ListViews are all the rage these days on Android because of the slick animations it displays when presenting data. When a user scrolls down, new items animate up into view, and quite frankly it looks awesome 
     **up_from_bottom.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="400" />
   </set>
```

Down from Top
    **down_from_top.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="400" />
    </set>
```

In your list adapter class

```
     private int lastPosition = -1;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//Load your view, populate it, etc...
      View view = ...;

    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), (position   > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
    view.startAnimation(animation);
    lastPosition = position;

    return view;
    }
```

copied from http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Implementing-Google-Plus-Style-ListView-Animations-on-Android

Comment: This is going to be applied each time you scroll, not only to the new Items in the list view like Google+